# sort an array function

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

**Picture**
[My program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ureQJ.jpg)

I'm making a program were you write in different sodas and rate them with points, I'm struggling to get it to sort the array after how many points the soda was given.

**Html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <script src = "Assignment08.js"></script>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Innlevering 8</h1>
    <img src="julebrus.jpg" alt="Julebrus" style="width:304px;height:228px;"><br>

    Brustype: <input id = "brustype" /><br>
    Poeng:    <input id = "poeng" /><br>

    <input type = "button" value = "Legg til brus" onclick = "leggTilBrus()" />

    <b><br>Liste over brus:</b>
    <div id = "brusliste"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
var brusliste = [];

function Brus(sodatype, points) { // Brus = Soda (English)
    this.brustype = sodatype;
    this.poeng = points;

    this.sodainfo = function() {
        return this.brustype + " " + this.poeng;
    }
}

function leggTilBrus(){
    var sodatype = document.getElementById("brustype").value;
    var points = document.getElementById("poeng").value;

    var sodas = new Brus (sodatype, points);

    brusliste.push(sodas);
    visArray();
}

function sortFunction(tall1,tall2){
    return tall1.verdi-tall2.verdi;
}

function visArray() {
    document.getElementById("brusliste").innerHTML = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < brusliste.length; i++){
        document.getElementById("brusliste").innerHTML += brusliste[i].sodainfo() + "<br />";
    }
}

function init() {
    var b = new Brus(" ", " ");

    console.log(b);
    console.log(b.sodainfo());

    document.getElementById("brusliste").innerHTML =  b.brustype + " <br />";

    brusliste.sort(sortFunction);
    //brusliste.sort(sorteringsFunksjon());
}

window.onload = init;
```

I need to write some more to get the post accepted x) anyway, any help will be appreciated. This thing is making my brain twist.

Comment: Using arithmetic operation can give you incorrect values. Rather use ternary operator: `a.prop > b.prop ? 1 : a.prop < b.prop ? -1 : 0`

Comment: Where does the `verdi` property come from?

Comment: Where does the verdi property come from? I'm not sure, just trying out what was done in the class. But didn't really understand it then, so I'm crashing and burning because of it now

Comment: Well, obviously you can’t sort by a property that doesn’t even exist. Try one that does exist. Which property do you want to sort by? Is it numeric or is it a string? Then search for how to sort by a numeric or a string property. Read [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) on how `sort` works.

Comment: it's going to be sorted by the points (Poeng). I have been looking at the examples on w3schools, but haven't been able to get my program to do the same so far.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work

```
function Brus(brustype, poeng) {
    this.brustype = brustype;
    this.poeng = poeng;

    this.brusinfo = function () {
        return this.brustype + " " + this.poeng;
    };
}

var brusliste = [];

function leggTilBrus() {
    var brustype = document.getElementById("brustype").value;
    var poeng = document.getElementById("poeng").value;

    var sodas = new Brus (brustype, poeng);

    brusliste.push(sodas);
    visArray();

    document.getElementById("brustype").value = "";
    document.getElementById("poeng").value = "";
}

function sortFunction(a, b){
    return b.poeng - a.poeng;
}


function visArray() {
    brusliste.sort(sortFunction);
    document.getElementById("brusliste").innerHTML = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < brusliste.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById("brusliste").innerHTML += brusliste[i].brusinfo() + "<br />";
    }
}

function init() {
    var b = new Brus(" ", " ");

    console.log(b);
    console.log(b.brusinfo());

    document.getElementById("brusliste").innerHTML =  b.brusinfo() + " <br />";
} 

window.onload = init;
```

I had done the sortfunction wrong, and was also missing two getElementById. This area:

```
        document.getElementById("brustype").value = "";
        document.getElementById("poeng").value = "";
    }

    function sortFunction(a, b){
        return b.poeng - a.poeng;
    }
```